# Proving the inequality $4(\ln 3)^2/33+187/(15\pi^{3/2}) < \sqrt{29}-3.$ without a calculator

Tags: inequality

I need help showing that

$$\frac{4(\ln 3)^2}{33}+\frac{187}{15\pi^{3/2}} < \sqrt{29}-3.$$

I've tried many methods, however could not prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these quantities can be calculated by hand to any degree of precision needed.

For $\pi$, the Nilakantha method converges reasonably quickly to the real value:

$$\pi = 3 + \frac{4}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} - \frac{4}{4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6} + \frac{4}{6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8} - \cdots$$

And,

$$\ln 3 = 2 - \frac{2^2}{2} + \frac{2^3}{3} - \frac{2^4}{4} + \cdots$$

For the square roots, [there are a bunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

I'd be sure to verify bounds for the errors at each step; they're well-defined.

Comment: This seems to be about as close as I will get.